# Remove 'webroot' from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

This is my project structure:

```
htdocs
-abs (project)
    - apps
    -----admin
    -----pc
    -----client
    -----Common
    - webroot
    -----htaccess (1) (for pc)
    -----index.php (for pc)
    -----admin
    --------htaccess (2)
    --------index.php
    -----client
    --------htaccess (3)
    --------index.php
```

.htaccess (1) content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

htaccess (2 & 3) content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I access via port like:

> http://localhost:8080/admin/

It ok.

But when I access not via port like:

> http://localhost/abs/admin

It redirect to

> http://localhost/abs/**webroot**/admin

I want to remove 'webroot' from

> http://localhost/abs/**webroot**/admin

How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

isn't it should be like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and use cake routing to create admin URL , its not related to htaccess

Comment: Thanks, but website has been released. So I can't change to use cake routing.

Comment: @Bàn Chân Trần you tried the htaccess code which i mentioned ?